# How do i get my menu to produce correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I need be able to use a bootstrap nav menu however their is a probelm here I have attached navbar on the advance settings of a menu item in joomla however the menu does not look anything like it should do.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="banner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/images/us2pk.png" alt="US2PK"></a>
            </div>
             <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">

                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-7" style="none" />


            </div>
        </div><!--/.container-->
    </nav><!--/nav-->
```

Here menu is wrong 
http://us2pk.solitudesoftware.co.uk/how-us2pk-works

Here it is correct.
http://us2pk.solitudesoftware.co.uk/

Comment: You need to explain what is wrong. Is it the styling of the menu that is wrong? Or that the dropdown is missing.

Comment: its the styling that is missing properly

Answer (score 0):

Most importantly, the markup on the correct menu has `<li><a>|</a></li>` - elements between the actual menu elements. You can add something similar by adding new menu items to your menu between each item, where you choose menu item type System links->Text separator. Here you simply add a | as the title. This is rendered with `<li class="item-122 divider"><span class="separator ">|</span></li>`, and should be easy enough to style similar to the correct menu.